# Unable to read whole file, reads just one line

Tags: java, token

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
    String s = reader.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = s.split(" ");

    while(t < tokens.length){
        a = 0;

        while( a < 6 ) {
            if(tokens[t].equals(d[a])){
                System.out.println("found keyword -> " + tokens[t]);
                files = 1;
            }
            a++;
        }

        p = 0;

        while( p < 2 ) {
            if(tokens[t].equals(xyz[p])){
                System.out.println("found token -> " + tokens[t]);
                files2 = 1;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (files2 == 0 && files == 0){
            System.out.println("found identifier -> " + tokens[t]);
        }

        files = 0;
        files2 = 0;
        t++;
    }

    reader.close();
}
```

I posted something similar like this the other day, but however the while loop didn't fix it . Can some please help me through this. The problem is that it doesn't read the entire the file but only reads the one line, and that is the first line. I don't know what I am doing honestly. Thanks.

Comment: It's incredibly hard to see from your formatting, is the `reader` closed before or after the `while` loop?

Comment: Where the heck do you define `t`?  Your code simply starts using it without ever defining/assigning it.

Comment: Well Marc, i already defined the variables, but I just posted the neccessary part of of the code which needed work.

Comment: You should seriously learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, there is literally no need to read a line using scanner, and then split it. **The scanner class uses a delimiter.** You can just call  `while(scanner.hasNext()) { scanner.next() };` and it will provide you with exactly one word at a time, split by spaces.

Comment: Thanks user 184994 that fixed it!! :D .. so I am guessing that I really don't need to refer as a line. Thank you so much!

Comment: Update: - it doesn't fix it. It only reads one word.

Comment: @user1769881 As mentioned in the answers below, you also need to ensure that `reader.close()` is **outside** of the while loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying it is outside the loop, and yet still doesn't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you didn't reset t after the inside while. Try including the line

```
t=0;
```

before the inside loop.

I did not debug your code, but I assume that if the first line has a number of tokens that is equal or bigger than the second, when the second line is read t is already equal to tokens.length.

I hope it helps.

Comment: BINGO! Works 100%. Can you please explain furhter into why this solved this? I would love to learn, thanks.

Comment: The best way for you to understand is to use a debugger so that you will follow the value of the variables as the program progresses. I did that with pen and paper (we brazilians call it the "chinese method") and realized that the variable t would keep the value between executions of the inner loop.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are closing your reader (`reader.close();`) inside of the while loop.

As [@rlinden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356382/rlinden) just mentioned, be sure to reset your loop variables. Where you currently have `reader.close();` make sure to set `t = 0;` for the next loop or take [@user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780943/user184994)'s sage advice.

Either way, you'll need to move `reader.close();` outside of (below) the outermost while loop.

Is there any more code missing above this block? That could have a big effect on how the reader is functioning. Please post your new / edited code below the first block of code so I can see where any new problems are. Mark them with the tag **Update:**

I'll watch for edits and provide more advice if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by others, the `reader.close();` call is inside the `while(reader.hasNextLine())` loop.  This is causing the reader to be closed before the second line is ever read.  Move it outside the outermost loop (i.e. after the `}` on the following line).  Then address the issue of the variable `t` not getting set/reset.